# Understanding explicit bijection between two sets

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

I'm having a lot difficulty understanding the concept of explicit bijection and how to show an explicit bijection between two sets. My professor rushed through the topic during class and now I'm trying some practice problems and I'm so lost :(

How do I go about showing an explicit bijection? For example, (0,1) and [4,8)? What difference does ( and [ make?

Thanks so much.

Comment: The ( and [ mean that you cannot use for example $f(x)=4x+4$ as that will not send any $x \in (0,1)$ to $4 \in [4,8)$

Comment: $(0, 1) = \{x : 0 < x < 1\}$ and $[4, 8) = \{x : 4 \le x < 8\}$; parenthesis are with points that aren't included (note the strict inequalities) while brackets are for points that are included. See [interval notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_%28mathematics%29#Notations_for_intervals)

Answer (score 1):

The main difference that [ makes is, it complicates the example ;)

First, an uncomplicated example: here's a bijection $(0,1) \to (4,8)$:

$$ x \mapsto 4 + 4x$$
This first maps $x \in (0,1)$ to $4x \in (0,4)$ – that itself is a bijection – and then (via another bijection) translates $(0,4)$ to $(4,8)$.

You can biject *any* two open, closed, open-closed, or closed-open intervals in a similar way, with a simple linear function.

If $f \colon A \to B$ and $g \colon B \to C$ are bijections, then $g \circ f \colon A \to C$ is a bijection. To show that a bijection *exists* from $(0,1) \to [4,8)$, you only need to show that there is one from $(4,8)$ to $[4,8)$.

It's harder to specify a bijection from $(4,8)$ to $[4,8)$. Certainly it can't be order-preserving. It's best in this case to settle for its mere existence: the union of an infinite set $S$ with a finite set $F$ is an infinite set of the same size, which means: there exists a bijection $S \to S \cup F$.